# How to check and see if an output contains the desired elements from any list or not?

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-unittest, assert, django-unittest

I am trying to write tests for a particular app in django using the python's unittest library.

```
def test_permissions_for_admin(self):
    admin = Group.objects.get(name='Administrator')
    permisisons = admin.permissions.all()
    admin_permissions = ['add_ipaddress', 'change_ipaddress', 'delete_ipaddress', 'view_ipaddress', 'add_subnet', 'change_subnet', 'delete_subnet', 'view_subnet']
    
    for p in permissions:
        print(p.codename)
    
    for p in permissions:
        self.assertIn(p.codename, admin_permissions)
```

The Above code prints this, OUTPUT:

```
change_emailaddress
delete_emailaddress
view_emailaddress
add_ipaddress
change_ipaddress
delete_ipaddress
view_ipaddress
add_subnet
change_subnet
delete_subnet
view_subnet
view_group
change_organization
change_organizationowner
add_organizationuser
change_organizationuser
delete_organizationuser
view_organizationuser
add_user
change_user
delete_user
view_user
```

Whereas What I am trying to check is that, all the permissions present from the variable `admin_permissions` are present in this output or not.

I have tried using the `assertIn`, `assertEqual`, & `assertTrue` methods but it doesn't seem to work here. Is there anything else I could look for or any method present which I am not aware of to solve such kind of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the `admin` has all the permissions, you need to do this the other way around, so:

```
perms = list(admin.permissions.values_list('codename', flat=True))
for p in admin_permissions:
    self.assertIn(p, perms)
```

we here thus check that for *each* item in `admin_permissions`, it is a member of `perms`: the `codename`s of the `.permissions` of `admin`.